# Where to store millions of HTML files

Tags: python, http, nosql

I have up to 100 million HTML static files. I need them for my software. Where can I store that many HTML files and access them when I need them?

**Solution #1**. Just in some folder. Is this OK? Is this hard for hdd? Should I create many sub-folders?

**Solution #2**. [Redis](http://redis.io/).

Please help me decide. I need to read these files once a month, very rarely. What solution leads to the best performance?

Comment: What do you mean by "read", and how many do you need to read once a month?

Comment: Why don't you use a db to store file paths and during runtime query the db e.g for 1 million file paths and in your code read the files one by one

Comment: What is it that you want to do once a month? If you only need to do it rearly, how important is the prefomance, or is it simplicity what you need? Whats the size of those files?

Comment: i need to read all of them once a month. I need simplicity. Size is ~50kb average.

Comment: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/ once you set this up, you can index millions of documents and retrieve them in milliseconds. that's not suitable for your "simplicity" tho, since you'll have to learn it...

Comment: I'd stick them in a folder -- because it is easy to do -- and worry about performance if it later on turned out to be a problem.

Comment: If you're going for simplicity just put them in a folder. Alternatively you could try putting them in a SQL database.

Comment: Store them in disk in a way you can easily find the html you want and let the os manage the caching for you. Depending on the File system may be a good idea to split them into several folders..

Answer (score 0):

"need to read all of them once a month" means no performance pressure at all. And since OP "need simplicity", an obvious choice is to store those files into file system, distributed among many hierarchical directories.

Something like this: https://serverfault.com/questions/95444/storing-a-million-images-in-the-filesystem